# Adding numbers from text file in batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've got a problem with batch script. I have to make script which adds numbers located within a text file.

The numbers are in one line of the file and separated by spaces.

I have to do it using a `for` loop.

I've made this:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a wynik=0
for /f "tokens=1* delims= " %%a in (liczby.txt) do (set /a wynik+=%%a)
echo %wynik% > wynik.txt
```

The output is:

```
C:\Users\NuClear\Desktop\arch\2>setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

C:\Users\NuClear\Desktop\arch\2>set /a wynik=0

C:\Users\NuClear\Desktop\arch\2>for /F "tokens=1* delims= " %a in (liczby.txt) do (set /a wynik+=%a )

C:\Users\NuClear\Desktop\arch\2>(set /a wynik+=1 )

C:\Users\NuClear\Desktop\arch\2>echo 1  1>wynik.txt
```

I've got no idea why it is not taking next `tokens` after `1`.

Comment: You have asked your `for` loop to parse the output as two individual tokens separated by the space delimiter, the first token is the first non space character string on the line, passed as `%a`, the second token is all other characters following the space character after that first string, passed as `%b`. So if your line reads as `1 2 3 4 5`, the first token, `%a`, will be `1`, and the second token, `%b`, will be `2 3 4 5`. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?` and read through the help and usage information of the command you are wanting to use, to better understand how to do so.

Comment: What about this: `for /F "tokens=*" %%J in (liczby.txt) do set /A "wynik=0" & for %%I in (%%J) do set /A "wynik+=%%I"`, then `> wynik.txt echo/%wynik%`?

Comment: @aschipfl %%J was unexpected at this time

Comment: @Compo i've tried to understand for /? but still i cannot make it. as %a stands for first element without rest, why %b cannot be the second one and so on

Comment: That is simply because you have requested two tokens, `1` and `*`, which for better understanding should have technically been written as `1,*`.

Comment: NuClear1331 I had no problems using @aschipfl 's code in a batch file.

Comment: @NuClear1331, 1. did you copy-and-paste the code from my comment? I guess you have got a type somewhere; 2. you seem to misunderstand the concept of `for /F`, which iterates through *lines*, and per line/iteration, *all* of the specified tokens are returned…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler method:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set /P "line=" < liczby.txt
set /A "wynik=%line: =+%"
> wynik.txt echo %wynik%
```

This method assumes that *"The numbers are in one line of the file and separated by **one space each**"*, with no spaces at beginning or end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify if you have to use `for` to read the file or just for the adding part.

```
REM read the (first line of the) file into a variable:
<liczby.txt set /p "line="
REM or using a FOR /F to read the file:
REM for /f "delims=" %%a in (liczby.txt) do set "x=%%a"
REM add them up:
set "y=0"
for %%a in (%line%) do set /a y+=%%a
echo Sum: %y%
```

`for /f` with `tokens` is extremely helpful, if you know beforehand, how many tokens there are. A plain `for` just executes for each token (using standard delimiters), how many there may be.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me, from the information you've provided, that the simplest idea would be to replace the single spaces with the addition operator.

Here's an example written for your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) tag:

```sh
@(
    For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%G In (
        "liczby.txt"
    ) Do @(
        Set "}=%%G"
        For /F "Delims=" %%H In (
            '%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /V /D /C "Set /A "!}: ^=+!""'
        ) Do @Echo(%%H
    )
) 1>"wynik.txt"
```

And for your [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) tag:

```sh
(For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %G in ("liczby.txt") Do @Set "}=%G" & For /F "Delims=" %H In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /V /D /C "Set /A "!}: ^=+!""') Do @Echo(%H) 1>"liczby.txt"
```

---

The current responses have possibly read into your question in a different way, due to its lack of clarity or examples, so my answer above assumes that `liczby.txt` looks a little like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9
10 11 12
13 14
```

…and the resultant `wynik.txt` would look something like this:

```
15
30
33
27
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option if you want to do it with a single `FOR` command. The key to this option is using `CMD.exe` with the `/U` option.

```
 @echo off
 set "wynik=0"
 for /F "delims=" %%G in ('cmd /D /U /C type liczby.txt ^| find /V ""') do (
    set /A "wynik+=%%G" 2>nul
 )
 >wynik.txt echo %wynik%
```

Comment: What if a number has got more than a single digit?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have got a text file `liczby.txt` with a content like this:

> ```cmd
> 1 2 3
> ```

When you read it with a `for /F` loop there is going to be one iteration because there is only a single line. Within this iteration all the tokens specified by the option string are returned in respective meta-variables.

But what you need is something else, you want to iterate through the individual numbers, which can be achieved using a standard `for` loop:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem // Initialise sum:
set /A "wynik=0"
rem // Read the input text file line by line:
for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%J in ("liczby.txt") do (
    rem // Loop through individual items/numbers:
    for %%I in (%%J) do (
        rem // Sum up the numbers:
        set /A "wynik+=%%I"
    )
)
rem // Write sum into output file:
> "wynik.txt" echo(%wynik%
endlocal
exit /B
```